# How to disable a button after clicking it once along with Confirmation message alert while clicking using VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

**Page Load function:**

```
btnGenerateBill.Attributes.Add("onclick", "var yesno=confirm('Please Confirm'); return yesno;")
btnGenerateBill.Attributes.Add("onclick", " this.disabled = true; " + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnGenerateBill, Nothing) + ";")
```

**Button click event :**

```
 Protected Sub btnGenerateBill_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGenerateBill.Click

        some code here

    End Sub
```

While clicking the button first time I get a confirmation message but the button is not disabling at once.

Comment: just add in Your button click event `btnGenerateBill.Enabled = False` and Your button will be disabled. btw. If `confirm` return `false` then code behind (click event) will not be triggered, and button will stay enabled.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Firstly don't use both the **page load** functions.*
**Use either one :**

```
btnGenerateBill.Attributes.Add("onclick", 
                               "var yesno=confirm('Please Confirm'); return yesno;")
```

or

```
btnGenerateBill.Attributes.Add("onclick",  
                  " this.disabled = true; " + 
                   ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnGenerateBill, Nothing) + ";")
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has the .one() function that limits any given event (i.e "submit") to one occurrence. Please look at this article:
http://api.jquery.com/one/

```
$('#myForm').one('submit', function() {
    $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```